# Irrigated Area Recognition in Google Earth Engine

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, ndvi

I'm using Google Earth Engine with the Python API. 
I have calculated the NDVI value over an area, set a threshold and the result is a **layer where black areas exceed my NDVI threshold** (don't pay attention to the red and blue dots, they are not important in this issue)

[image]

Now, I want to automatically **identify these black areas** (the ones that exceed a given extension) and save their position in order **to get a list of the (probably) irrigated camps in this ROI**.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for **vectorization**: a transformation of the raster image into vector areas.

You can probably use the `rasterio.features.shapes()` function from the Python's `rasterio` package, which gives out GeoJSON-like coordinates of contiguous areas of the same value from the raster, and then potentially use `shapely` to convert the areas to centroids to have simple point coordinates for each camp.

Given that your example above contains a considerable amount of noise (very small black areas), you might want to do some binary [opening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opening_(morphology)) or [closing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_(morphology)) to remove it, for example using `scipy.ndimage`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will try to remove the noise and then proceed to the vectorization, hoping that all will work properly!